# TLS - Where are tls handshakes usually performed for MQTT brokers?

Tags: ssl, erlang, mqtt, tls1.2

Right now I am working on altering EMQtt, and Erlang MQTT broker, so that I can perform a TLS handshake with Pre-Shared Keys, rather than an asymmetric method.

So far, I have gone through just about every file in the source code and cannot find any crypto-functions. So that gets me thinking, where could they possibly be performed? The application must have some control - in the configuration file it makes you specify the key, cert, and certificate authority certificates - so am I right in assuming that the application does handle the handshake? Or is there some kernel interface?

IF anyone can point me in the right direction or let me know if I am wrong in my understanding, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *guess* that TLS is handled first, and then socket connections are passed over to the MQTT handing code.

tserve can do this already, if you don't want to write your own code:
https://github.com/trafero/tstack/blob/master/docs/tserve.md

Otherwise, this might be a good place to start:
http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/design.html